# Repost- How to keep running total with switch case

Tags: c++, class, object, methods, switch-statement

I am writing a program that is like a guessing die and card game. It simulates the user rolling a die, and based on what they toll a card is generated that is equivalent to the amount of points they received in that round based. For example, rolling 1 has a card that says the user caught a big fish, and earned 20 points. The problem that I have is incrementing points and keeping a running total. The program only displays the die number rolled, as opposed to how many points were earned that round. It also does not print the correct final total. I have been tinkering with it for a few days, which leads me to believe I am making a simple mistake. Please help. My code is pasted below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Dice {
private:

public:
    int dicevalue;

    int rollDice() {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int dicevalue = rand() % 6 + 1;
        return dicevalue;
    }
};

class Points {

public:
    int total;
    int dicevalue;

    int Points::getpoints(int dicevalue) {
        switch (dicevalue) {

            case 1:
                cout << "\nYou rolled " << dicevalue << " \n" << endl;
                cout << "Huge Fish \n";

                total = 0 + 20;


                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "\nYou rolled " << dicevalue << " \n" << endl;
                cout << "Old shoe \n";

                total = 0 + 5;

                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "\nYou rolled " << dicevalue << " \n" << endl;
                cout << "Little Fish\n";

                total = 0 + 10;

                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "\nYou rolled " << dicevalue << "\n" << endl;
                cout << "Small prawn\n";

                total = 0 + 7;

                break;
            case 5:
                cout << "\nYou rolled " << dicevalue << "\n" << endl;
                cout << "Shark\n";

                total = 0 + 40;

                break;
            case 6:
                cout << "\nYou rolled " << dicevalue << "\n" << endl;
                cout << "Huge Catfish\n";

                total = 0 + 30;

                break;
        }

        return total;

    }

    int getPoints() {
        return dicevalue;
    }


};

class Game : public Points {


private:

    Dice dice;
    Points points;

public:

    int Game::playgame() {

        int choice, points_to_add;

        total = 0;
        points_to_add = 0;
        int dicevalue = dice.rollDice();
        total = total;
        points_to_add = total + points.getpoints(dicevalue);
        cout << "The value of total is: " << total << endl;
        //total = total + points_to_add;



        cout << "You earned:" << total << " points this round" << endl;


        //system("pause");

        return total;
    }
/*
        int getPoints() {
            return total;
        }
        */

};

int main() {
    int choice;
    int mytotal = 0, total, points_to_add = 0;
    Game game;

    do {


        cout << "Welcome to Go Fish 2.0!" << endl;
        game.playgame();

        cout << "Would you like to play again?" << endl;
        cout << "1 to play, 0 to exit: " << endl;
        cin >> choice;

    } while (choice == 1);
    mytotal = points_to_add + game.playgame();
    cout << "My Total game points are" << mytotal << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Probably not related to your error, but you should only call `srand` once per program. Don't both inherit from `Points` and have it as a member. I recommend keeping it only as a member (although its logic could probably just be placed in a standalone function). `total = total;` this does nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute correct running total using class objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263523/how-to-execute-correct-running-total-using-class-objects)